# Ubuntu Studio 20.10: Audacity 2.4.2 failing to record with Behringer UMC404HD interface

Tags: ubuntu-studio, audacity

I have just freshly installed Ubuntu Studio 20.10 on my desktop computer. I have connected a Behringer UMC404HD interface to my desktop via USB. When I attempt to record in the default installed version of Audacity, I get a variety of different strange behaviors. In all cases, it cannot record for more than a couple seconds.

I can record fine using this interface in a different partition, where I have Debian 9 installed. Their repos have an older version of Audacity.

Here are the specific behaviors I'm seeing:

1. Press 'R' on keyboard to begin recording
2. The following error message appears in a popup:

> Error opening device
> Error code: -9993 Illegal combination of I/O devices.

If I change the audio output device from "sysdefault" to "default" and attempt to record, I get the same error message.

Here are my settings in Audacity:

- Input device: UMC404HD 192k: USB Audio (hw:1,0)
- Number of channels: 2
  (Stereo) Record Channels
- Output device: "sysdefault" or "default"

When I try changing the output device to "front" (for headphones?), I get the following error message in a popup:

> Error opening recording device
> Error code: -9997 Invalid sample rate

I have not touched the sample rate. It is set to the default of 44,100 Hz.

Before typing this post, at some point, Audacity was able to record for a second or two. All I did was mess around with the inputs and outputs.

When I switch to a different interface (Behringer UMC1820), it seems to be able to record fine. But I want to use my other interface (UMC404HD).

Comment: Are you using jack server? I currently use Kubuntu LTS with UbuntuStudio backports PPA enable and audio software installed. No trouble at all with Behringher UMC404HD some months ago, but a I don't use Audacity, I recorded using Ardour or Reaper. Any particular reason for using UbuntuStudio 20.10?

Comment: @rolodoom: I seem to remember reading Audacity doesn't support JACK. Maybe I'm thinking of something else. In any case, I haven't done anything special to set up my system, other than install Ubuntu Studio 20.10 and launch Audacity. The main Audacity window says "ALSA" (the only option), not "JACK." I haven't tried Ardour, but I may try that next. Regarding choosing 20.10 (as opposed to 20.04, the LTS release), I saw that 20.10 introduced the KDE Plasma desktop and that they plan to use it in the future, so I figured it made more sense to get used to that.

Answer (score 1):

On UbuntuStudio, it's possible to record on Audacity using Ardour.

1- You need to install jack and studio controls and use studio controls to enable jack and make sure there is a Pulse Jack Bridge. This means that all outputs and inputs will be trapped by the jack server and the only option available on the system will be Jack sink (for the output) and Jack source (for the input).

[image: Studio Controls]

[image: Available audio sources on plasma after enabling Pulse Jack Bridge]

2- The, the jack will be an available option on Audacity, but it really doesn't matter because all audio traffic will be redirected to the Pulse Jack Bridge.

[image: Audacity preferences]

I always use the jack server when recording audio. I hope this helps you to find the problem. I can tell you that I recorded an album using that interface and had no problem at all using UbuntuStudio.